# Running Kafka on Windows 10 fails: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run Kafka locally. I've got Zookeeper installed and running. I've downloaded the binaries for Kafka 2.11-1.1.0. I've adjusted the location of the logs in `server.config`, to a valid path. When I run `.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`, I get an error that says

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I can see that both those files exist on my computer in the proper locations-what should I be troubleshooting?
[image: kafka-server-start: check]
[image: server.config: check]

Comment: Please show text as text. Showing text as an image, is a serious accessibility issue.

Comment: You can find more details here https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/08/30/kafka-2-6-up-and-running-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I faced this issue while running the kafka-server-start.bat command. I double checked to ensure that there was no spaces in the kafka binaries path as well as correct syntax in JAVA_HOME.

Finally realized that the issue was due to a space in the JAVA_HOME path.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

There is a space between Program and Files. I changed the directory of Java and updated the JAVA_HOME variable to

> C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

This change solved my issue. I used the setx command to change the value in JAVA_HOME.

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
```

Comment: If you don't want to move Java, you can set JAVA_HOME to the shortened path, for example: set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.1

Comment: Changing java path from "program files" to "C:\Java" works for me. now my zookeeper and Kafka are up and running 
Thanks! @Joyson

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem as well.  In my case I have java installed in C:\Java\bin and JAVA_HOME defined as

JAVA_HOME=c:\Java\bin

I needed to change

> c:\Tools\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\kafka-run-class.sh

lines 224 to 229 from this

```
# Which java to use
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
  JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
```

to this:

```
# Which java to use
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
  JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/java"
fi
```

because it was assigning java to C:\Java\bin/bin/java
which was then failing on 306 of the same file.

BTW: I'm using a git bash shell in windows. This allows me to run the bin/*.sh scripts instead of the bin/windows/*.bat scripts

Also I changes the value of the dataDir in

> C:\Tools\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\config\zookeeper.properties

to

```
dataDir=C:\\Tools\\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\\zookeeper-data
```

Comment: For Windows .bat file, the line to modify is 161

Comment: @WalidChiko something like `kafka-run-class.bat` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes ! i tried your method but i got this error :

C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
[2020-07-08 17:55:15,487] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-07-08 17:55:15,710] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "zookeeper.connect" which has no default value.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:477)
....@Frakcool

Comment: Did you change the `zookeepet.properties` file? @WalidChiko tbh I'm not sure what might be happening, I suggest you to ask a new question. I'm not an expert at kafka

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that this error is being thrown by `kafka-run-class.bat` because the path to `JAVA_HOME` in system variables is malformed (in my case, I had added /bin to it.) Removing /bin from the path, and having it be an existing Java installation folder, makes everything run fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but it wasn't because of the malformed path of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

It was because I had extracted my kafka bineries in a path which contains spaces!

First it was here:

> E:\Apache Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0

Then I relocate it in this new path (which doesn't have any spaces!):

> E:\ApacheKafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0

And the problem resolved!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

As many have mentioned, this can happen if any of the kafka *.bat scripts that you run ( including zookeeper) refer to a bad JAVA_HOME system variable, or one containing a space.

You can solve this by changing JAVA_HOME to the shortened path name.
For example

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.1
```

P.S.

For convenience, I created a CMD desktop shortcut that sets the JAVA_HOME to be right for Kafka, and CDs to my kafka installation. My Desktop shortcut is as follows:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-11.0.1&  f: & cd f:\kafka\kafka_2.12-2.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing answer, you can also get the error when running the *Kafka provided* `zookeeper-server-start` command (and almost all other scripts in the `bin/windows` folder) because it also utilizes `kafka-run-class`, and therefore relies on a valid `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path.

```
cd D:\Downloads\kafka
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Comment: For me, it was putting the period at the beginning of the paths. Thanks for the indirect solution

Answer (score 2):

I think JAVA_HOME should keep till JDK path not JDK\bin.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I hope it helps someone. I had the same issue, and found someone had updated JAVA to a newer version, i.e. my JAVA_HOME system variable was pointing to a folder that didnt exist. Strange as I hadnt done it, but the answers above inspired me to check it.

Answer (score 1):

I facing same issue and fixed with below steps as following:

- Make sure your environment variable as:

  `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261`

  `ZOOKEEPER_HOME=C:\apache-zookeeper-3.6.2`

  `KAFKA_HOME=C:\kafka_2.13-2.7.0`
- Edit the '**Path**' in system variable and type:
  `%JAVA_HOME% / bin, %ZOOPKEEPER_HOME / bin and %KAFKA_HOME% / bin`
- Now, open the terminal, Run zoopkeeper and kafka

  For **Zoopkeeper**: `zkserver`

  For **Kafka**: `bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties`

It runs without an any issues and errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions, I changed JAVA_HOME different methods and it didn't work.
Solution:
launch cmd.exe as administrator and execute the command:
**set JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-17.0.1**
(only will choice your jdk version)

Comment: This action of setting JAVA_HOME did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had been stuck with this for quite some time. Following are the steps I followed to resolve the issue:

- In enviroment variables set **JAVA_HOME** to **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath**
- If the above doesn't resolve the issue, check if in **kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh** JAVA=**$JAVA_HOME/bin/java** is used. In this case you might need to simply create a folder **bin** under **javapath** and copy the **java.exe** to it. This should fix the isssue.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of main, in Environment variables set JAVA_HOME in Both part
User variables & system variables And the problem resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java_home path is correct with respect to the directory. This issue happens when the java_home path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I relocate it into the new path and I provide this zookeeper bin path properly into environment variable setup and it work for me fine.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution that worked for me -
Open kafka-run-class.sh file, goto line num 306, enclose $JAVA within "".

exec "$JAVA" $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"

This problem appears if there a space in your Java path. Either remove the space from your Java installation path or enclose the path within double-quotes.