# How can i force Kafka to run on 64 bit JVM?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

i'm using a computer that has the 2 versions 32bits and 64bit of java. 
i want to run kafka and it keeps launching outOfMemory Exception which i discovered after some researches is due to java32bits version. everyone says that switching to 64bit version of java solved the issue.
running java - version gives me the following output

> java version "1.8.0_91"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

but i think that kafka is using the 32 bits version also installed on the computer ( and i cant remove)
kafka version is 2.12-2.2.0 and i'm running kafka on windows

Comment: Kafka doesn't start with that much memory by default... How much does your machine actually have? Also: Kafka is not tested extensively on windows anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the scripts under `/bin` use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to select the java runtime.

See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/windows/kafka-run-class.bat#L158

If you have several JVMs installed, be sure to set this variable accordingly, so Kafka picks the version you want.

Comment: i changed the JAVA_HOME and made it point to java64 bits and now i'm getting specified path is not found when i try to run zookeeper :/

Comment: @kmarakrout, run "ps -ef" and check for your broker process. This process will give you complete java path from which you can identify which version of java is you Kafka using.

Comment: Also what are the XMS and XMX values set for your broker and what is the available memory on machine where  your broker is running.

Comment: now that i changed the java version of the javaHome variable my broker isnt running it just says path not found when i write the command for the starting of zookeeper As for the XMS and XMX i didnt change anything ! i got the kafka as it is from the officialWebsite

Answer (score 0):

in addition of changing the version of java in the JAVA_HOME env variable i had to make it without spaces. that's what was causing the second problem of specified path not found. 
this question helped me:

> [Running Kafka on Windows 10 fails: The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120971/running-kafka-on-windows-10-fails-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)